# magento2 saving data via observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

i'm new in magento 2
I want to save some data into custom table after customer click place order
I'm done it in magento 1
Below is my magento 1 code :

config.xml : `app\code\local\Sprint\Migs\etc`

```
 <events>
      <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <observers>
          <sprint_migs_saveSiteID>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Sprint_Migs_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>saveSiteID</method>
          </sprint_migs_saveSiteID>
        </observers>
      </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
</events>
```

Observer.php : `app\code\local\Sprint\Migs\Model`

```
public function saveSiteID($observer){
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
    if(isset($post['payment']['method'])){
        if ($post['payment']['method'] == "migs"){

            $order                  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $merchantTransactionID  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
            $siteId                 = $post['payment']['site_id'];
            $transactionType        = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/migs/transactionType');
            $currency               = 'IDR';
            $amount                 = Mage::helper('migs')->getTotalPrice($merchantTransactionID);

            $data       = array("merchantTransactionID" => $merchantTransactionID,"siteId" => $siteId,"transactionType" => $transactionType,"currency" => $currency,"amount" => $amount);  
            Mage::helper('migs')->insertMigsData($data);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Data.php : `app\code\local\Sprint\Migs\Helper`

```
<?php

class Sprint_Migs_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    public function getTotalPrice($transactionNo="") {
        if ($transactionNo != ""){
            $order              = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($transactionNo);
            $baseCode           = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();      
            $allowedCurrencies  = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies(); 
            $rates              = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));
            if($baseCode == 'IDR') {
                $TotalWithPeriod = explode('.', $order->getBaseGrandTotal());
                $totalPrice     = $TotalWithPeriod[0];
            }
            else {
                $totalPriceRate = $order->getBaseGrandTotal()*$rates['IDR'];
                $TotalWithPeriod = explode('.', $totalPriceRate);
                $totalPrice = $TotalWithPeriod[0];
            }
        }else{
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($session);
            $baseCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
            $allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies(); 
            $rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));
            if($baseCode == 'IDR') {
                $TotalWithPeriod = explode('.', $order->getBaseGrandTotal());
                $totalPrice = $TotalWithPeriod[0];
            }
            else {
                $totalPriceRate = $order->getBaseGrandTotal()*$rates['IDR'];
                $TotalWithPeriod = explode('.', $totalPriceRate);
                $totalPrice = $TotalWithPeriod[0];
            }
        }

        return $totalPrice;
    }

    public function getUrlData( $st ){
        $st = strtolower($st);
        $url = array(
            'development' => 'https://training.doappx.com/sprintAsia/api/webAuthorization.cfm',
            'production' => 'https://acquire.doappx.com/sprint/doacquire/api/webAuthorization.cfm'
        );
        return $url[ $st ];
    }

    public function getSiteID($merchantTransactionID) {
        $resource               = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $read                   = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        $sql                    = ("SELECT siteId FROM sprint_migs WHERE merchantTransactionID = '".$merchantTransactionID."'");
        $result                 = $read->fetchRow($sql);
        $siteID                 = $result['siteId'];
        return $siteID;
    }

    public function insertMigsData($data){
        $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $write      = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $table      = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getTableName( 'sprint_migs' ); 
        $write->insert($table, $data);
    }

    public function updateMigsData($data,$where) {
        $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $write      = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $table      = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getTableName( 'sprint_migs' ); 
        $write->update($table, $data, $where);
    }

    public function generateInvoice( $order ){
        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
        if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
        }
        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
        $invoice->register();
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($invoice)
                ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

        $transactionSave->save();
    }
}
```

how can i do it in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by creating an observer

[Namespace]/[Modulename]/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="obeserver_name" instance="[Namespace]\[Modulename]\Observer\AfterOrderPlaced" />
    </event>
</config>
```

[Namespace]/[Modulename]/Observer/AfterOrderPlaced

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterOrderPlaced implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_status=$order->getStatus();
        //DO YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE

    }
}
```

Hope that Helps.

Comment: How to set it to custom table after an event triggers.

Comment: Hi @PrathapGunasekaran, did got the answer for save it custom table